# Performing arithmetic operations on lvalue

Tags: c++

I understood that the following C++ expression

```
j * 4 = 7; // C2106
```

is incorrect because an lvalue is expected at the left hand side.
If I guess right, the variable **j** is infact an lvalue but performing
an arithmetic operation `j * 4` results in an rvalue. Therefore, is it right
to say performing an arithmetic operation like addition on an **lvalue** will
always result in an **rvalue**?

**If yes, is there any exceptions to this rule?**

**Note**: Let us not consider pointers for this question.

Comment: Is `+=` "an arithmetic operation like addition"?

Comment: @gha.st: Valid point. But it indeed does an assignment at the end. doesn't it?

Comment: See [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category). The `lvalue` section lists all the expressions which are lvalues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The built-in operators `+` (unary and binary), `-` (unary and binary), `*` (binary), `/`, `%`, `<<`, and `>>` yield prvalues ("pure" rvalues), without exception. (So do various other operators, which you would probably not consider to be arithmetic.) Furthermore, they all require their operands to be prvalues, so if they were originally lvalues, they undergo the implicit lvalue-to-rvalue conversion.

You're probably aware that the built-in compound assignment operators yield lvalues. A less well-known fact is that the built-in preincrement and predecrement operators also yield lvalues. So perhaps they're counterexample to your hypothesis that arithmetic operations always result in rvalues.

If you overload an operator, the value category of its return type can be whatever you wish. You can make `operator+` return `T&` if you want, where `T` is some class or enum type. Then the result of an addition could be an lvalue. But it's hard to think of when it would ever make sense to write such an operator.

Comment: Huh? "the built-in preincrement and postincrement operators also yield lvalues"? No way. "x++ = 7" doesn't compile, and neither does "((x++)++)".

Comment: @Atsby Sorry, I meant predecrement. Whoops.

Comment: @Atsby Try `++(++x)` or `++x = 7`. It should work. (Only in C++ though; not in C.)

Comment: `++(++x)` or `++x = 7;` might cause UB (sequencing violation) even though it is syntactically valid

Comment: Slightly more useful: `int* ptr = &(++x);`

Comment: @Brian Thankyou for pointing out **A less well-known fact is that the built-in preincrement and predecrement operators also yield lvalues**. Great stuff !!!

Comment: @MattMcNabb In C++11 there is no problem. `++x` is equivalent to `x += 1`, and the modification of `x` is sequenced before the value computation.

Comment: @Brian OK, so `++++++++++x;` is fine then :)

Answer (score -2):

> Therefore, is it right to say performing an arithmetic operation like addition on an lvalue will always change it to an rvalue?

Yes. **EDIT:** Actually, no. See other answers.

Comment: Any exceptions to this rule? Say I'm overloading an operator.

Comment: @sjsam Then you're not, strictly speaking, "performing an arithmetic operation" on the lvalue, you're invoking the overloaded operator. It is possible to return an lvalue from an overloaded operator in C++ (by returning a "reference").